# How to use Multi-Select Dropdown in react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using **react-bootstrap** library. This library having a module called **DropdownButton**. So i am able to display data in dropdown. This is single selection data.

```
  <DropdownButton
            bsStyle="success"
            title={this.state.addLeadStageSelectTitle}
            key={"addleadstageDropDown"}
            id={"addleadstageIDAdd"}
            onSelect={this.handleSelectLeadStageAdd}
            >
                {this.state.vtx_sales_lead_status.map(objs => {
                   return (
                     <MenuItem eventKey={objs.id}>{objs.name}</MenuItem>
                  )

                }
                  )}
          </DropdownButton>
```

But I am trying to create it **multiselect** with same library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a multi-select example using hooks and react-bootstrap.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Col, Form } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {
  const [field, setField] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="my_multiselect_field">
      <Form.Label>My multiselect</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control as="select" multiple value={field} onChange={e => setField([].slice.call(e.target.selectedOptions).map(item => item.value))}>
        <option value="field1">Field 1</option>
        <option value="field2">Field 2</option>
        <option value="field3">Field 3</option>
      </Form.Control>
    </Form.Group>
  );
}
```

Comment: What about the dropdown?

Comment: This is not a dropdown

Comment: This example is a multi-select without a dropdown. If you want the dropdown version, see the response from Jordan Enev.

Answer (score 7):

I've checked the `react-bootstrap` documentation and it looks like there isn't a **multiselect** functionality.

So you can use a third party library, like: [react-bootstrap-multiselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-multiselect).

> It's a Multiselect component for React (with Bootstrap). This is a React wrapper around an existing jQuery / Bootstrap library: [bootstrap-multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect)

**Basic usage**:

```
import Multiselect from 'react-bootstrap-multiselect'

const data = [{ value:'One', selected:true }, { value: 'Two' }, { value:'Three' }]

const App = props => {
  return <Multiselect onChange={props.handleChange} data={data} multiple />
}
```

[**Demo**](https://projects.skratchdot.com/react-bootstrap-multiselect/).

Answer (score 6):

It is supported now:

```
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';

// [........]

<Form>
  <Form.Control as="select" multiple value={options} onChange={onSelectedOptionsChange}>
    {options.map(option => (
      <option key={option.name} value={option.value}>
        {option.name}   
      </option>
    ))}  
  </Form.Control>
</Form>
```

Comment: This seems to be for a multiselect without any dropdown support.

Comment: Note that the selected options are in `e.target.selectedOptions` and not in `e.target.value`.

Answer (score 2):

Here a multi select with checkbox at the side of the options:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';

const MultiSelectDropdown = () => {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const options = [
    { id: 1, label: 'Option 1' },
    { id: 2, label: 'Option 2' },
    { id: 3, label: 'Option 3' },
    { id: 4, label: 'Option 4' },
    { id: 5, label: 'Option 5' }
  ];

  const toggleDropdown = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const handleOptionChange = (event) => {
    const optionId = parseInt(event.target.value);
    const isChecked = event.target.checked;

    if (isChecked) {
      setSelectedOptions([...selectedOptions, optionId]);
    } else {
      setSelectedOptions(selectedOptions.filter((id) => id !== optionId));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={`dropdown ${isOpen ? 'show' : ''}`}>
      <button
        style={{width:"20%"}}
        className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
        type="button"
        id="multiSelectDropdown"
        onClick={toggleDropdown}
      >
        Select Options
      </button>
      <div style={{width:"20%"}} className={`dropdown-menu ${isOpen ? 'show' : ''}`} aria-labelledby="multiSelectDropdown">
        {options.map((option) => (
          <Form.Check
          style={{marginLeft:"10%"}}
            key={option.id}
            type="checkbox"
            id={`option_${option.id}`}
            label={option.label}
            checked={selectedOptions.includes(option.id)}
            onChange={handleOptionChange}
            value={option.id}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      {JSON.stringify(selectedOptions)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MultiSelectDropdown;
```