# react-bootstrap-multiselect is not working properly in react-bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, multi-select, react-bootstrap

react-bootstrap-multiselect is not working properly in react-bootstrap 4. It is perfectly working with bootstrap 3.

While using react-bootstrap-multiselect with react-bootstrap4 Whenever I am trying to add any props like includeSelectAllOption or onChange then select menu stop working. As It is not showing select menu options

When I inspect html in web console. then I found that, it is adding one more empty ul tag and on the clicking on select menu. It is showing empty ul.

Please help me

```
import Multiselect from 'react-bootstrap-multiselect';
import 'react-bootstrap-multiselect/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css'

<Multiselect 
                            includeSelectAllOption
                            ref="option1" 
                            id="option1"
                            name="option1" 
                            data={this.state.option1} 
                            onChange={(value) => this.inputChanged(value, 'option1')}  
                        />
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide a codepen? Also are you seeing any console errors?

Comment: Why don't you try this - https://react-select.com/home

Comment: Also check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54573926/how-to-use-multi-select-dropdown-in-react-bootstrap

Comment: There is no any console error.  I am not able to provide you codepen. But I added code. I have used following npm package and used same syntax

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: I need select menu with checkbox option. which is not possible in case of react-select

Comment: @HIteshJain, Are you able to solve this issue? I am also facing similar issue.. Please help me..